# Create a random string from a string

Tags: php

I am trying to create a random string from a string.

```
$input = "123456789012345678901234567890"; 
$pieces = str_split($input); 
$rand_keys = array_rand($pieces , 10); 
$str = implode("", $rand_keys);
echo $str;



$input = "abcdefghilmnoABCDEFGHIKLMNO1234567890"; 
$pieces = str_split($input); 
$rand_keys = array_rand($pieces , 10); 
$str = implode("", $rand_keys);
echo $str;
```

But the output string is weird. Have a look: http://codepad.org/FwLU05DC

Both of them work: ( I prefer the first one)

```
    $input = "123456789012345678901234567890"; 
    $pieces = str_split($input); 
    foreach(array_rand($pieces , 10) as $key){ 
        $str .= $pieces[$key];
    }
    echo $str;


string str_shuffle ( string $str )
```

Finally:

```
$pieces = str_split('12345678901234567890abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQTUSVXYZW');
foreach(array_rand($pieces , 15) as $key){ $str .= $pieces[$key]; }
```

Comment: What's weird about it?

Comment: Looks fine, what did you want to output?

Comment: You are outputting the `keys` ... not the `values`

Comment: The thing is when I use letter in the string it still gives me numbers

Comment: @KevinAskin: `array_rand()` returns the keys from the array, not the values.  From the docs (http://php.net/array_rand): `an array of keys for the random entries is returned`.  I assumed you knew that since you named your variable `$rand_keys`.

Comment: you get what you asked for and are surprised ?

Comment: If you're going to be doing this, remember that as of PHP 5.2.10 the "random" keys will be returned *in the order they appear in the source array*. Use `shuffle()` if you want them... shuffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code updated to give you what you want ...

```
<?php
    $input = "123456789012345678901234567890"; 
    $pieces = str_split($input); 
    foreach(array_rand($pieces , 10) as $key){ 
        $str .= $pieces[$key];
    }
    echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you use str_shuffle?!

```
string str_shuffle ( string $str )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function generateString($what, $length) {
    $chars = $what;
    $rand = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $rand .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars) -1)];
    }
    return $rand;
}
$randstring = generateString($input, 10);
echo $randstring;
```

Comment: I have this in my code :( I just try to do something smaller )

Comment: Well, you can reuse that function anywhere on the site if you put it in like a general class. Nothing wrong with that. And you won't get as many collisions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :P I just thought about something new will be awesome

Comment: You gonna accept it???

Comment: @cmorrissey is what I am trying to do but I mean it will be better without `foreach` `while` or `for`

Comment: I am using a for loop her because I have to check if the variable **$i** is less than **$length**.